# determine a boolean value based on min and max value

Tags: python, database, for-loop, boolean

right now I have min, max value from table1 that defines the range of a value. There is a boolean column in table2 of which the value is determined by the min and max value in table1. If the actual number is within the range, the value would be F (means no problem), and vice versa. after i ran my codes, only the first two rows of the column came out as false. I don't know what's wrong with my codes. My codes of for loop block are as below. Of which, records1 is the actual values in table2, and records2 and records3 are minimum and maximum values from table1 respectively. I use this forloop statement to get single record of the three groups of numbers, and then in the if statement within it, I determine each value of the boolean column by checking if record1 falls in the range between min(record2) and max(record3) values.

```
    conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
    # conn.cursor will return a cursor object, you can use this cursor to perform queries

    #get the actual number
    curs1 = conn.cursor()
    statement='SELECT value FROM table2'
    curs1.execute(statement)
    records1=curs1.fetchall()

    #get the minimum number
    curs2 = conn.cursor()
    statement2='SELECT min FROM table1'
    curs2.execute(statement2)
    records2=curs2.fetchall()

    #get the maximum number
    curs3 = conn.cursor()
    statement3='SELECT max FROM table1'
    curs3.execute(statement3)
    records3=curs3.fetchall() 


    for record1 in records1:
        for record2 in records2:
            for record3 in records3:
                while record1 >= record2 and record1 <=record3::
                    statement4='UPDATE table2 SET column = false WHERE record1 >=   record2 and record1 <= record3'
                    curs4 = conn.cursor()
                    curs4.execute(statement4)

                else:
                    statement5='UPDATE table2 SET column = true WHERE record1 <= record2 or record1 >= record3'
                    curs5 = conn.cursor()
                    curs5.execute(statement5)
                conn.commit()
                conn.close()
```

Can someone point out where I am wrong? Tks in advance

Comment: When I see Python code pasted in I sometimes wonder if the indents are displayed correctly.  What is in the for loop?

Comment: it didnot give me any error of identation so i suppose it is correct. i have an identation before curs=.. , it just does not show up correctly here. the for loop is to get every single record of the three groups of numbers and determine each boolean value.

Comment: please edit your question and correct the indentation to match the [code](http://sscce.org/) you're using.

Comment: @outis: now it should be ok, tks

Comment: can you add the schema of your tables, what column names / keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the statement below:

```
 statement1='UPDATE table2 SET column= false WHERE value >= (SELECT min FROM table1 WHERE
 table1.common_name=table2.common_name) AND value <=(SELECT max FROM table1 WHERE 
 table1.common_name=table2.common_name)'
```

...

instead of using variable in the forloop, i used the select statement, within which I used a WHERE clause to define according record of min and max. This seems a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

take notice the way range works in python...

```
>>> range(1,5)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

You may be better off making your comparison statement:

`if record2 <= record1 <= record3:`

also from what it looks like you are updating the entire table with your statement instead of the row of the records in your comparision.

I think you are being redundant with the for loop, instead a sql statement should take care of what you are trying to accomplish or you need to pass in an id for the rows and use that for the WHERE clause.

Comment: @kriegar:the for loop is just to get single record of the column numbers. there is actually a forloop example, e.g.,                   for i in range(3): print i ...      so my statement should work.  i tried ur if record2<= .. statement but it didnot make a difference neither. And I do have a WHERE statement right within the statement to choose those ones that I need to change.

Comment: I think kriegar is right.  But I think he meant to say the `if record1 in range(record2, record3):` line (third line down) should be `if record2 <= record1 <= record3:`.

Comment: @dappawit: i tried the line: if record2 <= record1 <= record3:   it didnot make a difference

Comment: @widget your "statements" are flawed but i can't really help you adjust the here clause unless I know the setup of your two tables. Can you add them to your original post?

Comment: @kriegar: I don't have 'setup' of the tables. I simply connect to the database and then I could deploy them, as what u could see in my statement. What do you want to know about the table?

Comment: @kriegar: anyway, i edited my post and added the codes to get records1, records2, records3. I guess these codes may be flawed as well